# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'display')

Tags: javascript, button, undefined, toggle

I'm trying to toggle text showing when I click a button for each item I have in a Carousel.

When I use "getElementByID" it works fine, but I need to use "getElementsByClassName" because it's a repeater field in the backend and there are several buttons in the whole carousel.

Anyway here is my code -

```
 function toggleText(){
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("figure-caption-test");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

<button class="figure-button" id="figure-button" onclick="toggleText()">
REVEAL ANSWER
</button>

<figcaption class="figure-caption-test" id="reveal-text" style="display: none;">
Text that appears
</figcaption>
```

And the error i'm getting is -
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'display')

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: What do you think `getElementsByClassName` returns? How would your code be expected to work for multiple elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns array of elements.
this is my solution:

```js
 function toggleText(){
  var elms = document.getElementsByClassName("figure-caption-test");

  Array.from(elms).forEach((x) => {
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<button class="figure-button" id="figure-button" onclick="toggleText()">
REVEAL ANSWER
</button>

<figcaption class="figure-caption-test" id="reveal-text" style="display: none;">
Text that appears
</figcaption>
```

Answer (score 0):

"getElementsByClassName" returns an array-like object, not a single object.

You can iterate over the object using a forEach:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(x, function(element) {
  if (element.style.display === "none") {
      element.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      element.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
);
```

You can find more on that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: cant use `forEach` on the `getElementsByClassName` result.

Comment: Cotrrect, will edit my answer, you can do this:
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(x), function (element) {
      ...
    });

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a for loop missing and a counting variable.

Your code should look like this:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("figure-caption-test");
var i;
for (i=0; i < x.length; i++) { 

if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).